# Boot m.2 SSD PCIe - Gigabyte mobo and B85M chipset

Tags: boot, ssd, motherboard, m.2

Is there a way I can boot in my m.2 SSD?

I was able to recognize the drive in Windows and also start installing Win 10 on it, but I can't see how to boot!

Hardware configuration:

- Mobo model: GA-B85M-D3PH (BIOS F5, latest)
- SSD: Samsung [SSD 960 PRO](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/960pro.html)
- PCIe adapter: [Asus Hyper m.2 x4 mini card](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboard-Accessory/HYPER_M2_X4_MINI_CARD/)

Comment: I doubt based on the age of your motherboard you will be able to boot to NVMe based SSDs.  This is especially true due to the adapter you are forced to use.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a fresh install, but you must use GPT not MBR. Delete all partitions when starting the Windows installation. Set all BOOT options to "UEFI ONLY" where possible. Do a windows UEFI install. Make sure that the device is not a OCZ drive since it is not on the Gigabyte compatibility list but may work.

Comment: It will come down to whether your BIOS knows how to access a NVMe device.

Comment: I set to UEFI ONLY but after restart BIOS says no bootable device was found.